# How to render a nested view (relative view)

Tags: ember.js

I have the following (`ember-1.4.0`):

```
App.DateRangeSelectorView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'date-range-selector',
  selectedBinding: 'controller.selected',
  dateRangeSelectorItemView: Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    classNameBindings: ['isActive:active'],
    isActive: function() {
      return this.get('item') === this.get('parentView.selected');
    }.property('item', 'parentView.selected')
  })
});
```

And the template:

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="date-range-selector">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        {{#view view.dateRangeSelectorItemView item="today"}}
          <a href="#" {{action gotoToday}} >{{controller.content.today.label}}</a>
        {{/view}}

    ....

      </ul>
    </script>
```

I have followed the guidelines specified [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/inserting-views-in-templates/#toc_relative-paths), specially:

> When nesting a view class like this, make sure to use a lowercase
>   letter, as Ember will interpret a property with a capital letter as a
>   global property.

Thanks, but no thanks: ember is stubbornly saying:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Unable to find view at path 'view.dateRangeSelectorItemView'
```

I have tried with and without the `view.` prefix, but no luck. How can I render the nested view?

## EDIT

The problem seems to be that the lookup performed by the container is failing. Maybe there are some capitalization or name coercion rules that I am not getting right. I would like to list all available views, so that I can recognize if my view is there, maybe with a slightly different name.

How can I list all available (registered?) views, including nested views? That would include `dateRangeSelectorItemView`, which is a view nested inside `App.DateRangeSelectorView`, and is not defined in the application itself.

I guess what I am looking for is a way of listing all objects (with their lookup names!) which are extensions of `Ember.View`: `Ember.View.extend()`

Comment: Please, try to render the view using `{{#view App.DateRangeSelectorItemView item="today"}}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was using an outlet for this, and the outlet does not allow to specify a view: it generates the view according to the template name, so that my `DateRangeSelectorView` was not used. I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4392) about this.